# How do I figure out if DatePicker choice is today?

Tags: c#, date, datepicker

I want to be able to have the user select a date ( chances are higher that it'll always be "Today" ) but just in case. I want to check whats selected in the picker, compare to today.

Basicly:

```
if (DatePicker.Date.Month|Day|Year == DateTime.Today.Month|Day|Year|Today)
   var = (Pull date and Time)
else
   var = (Pull Date only)
```

Comment: Isn't it enough to compare it to DateTime.Today? Or maybe I miss something?

Comment: No, Im not sure how to compare. Questioning google has yeilded nothing on this question itself.

Comment: Can you shoe the code you are trying to write? The one in the question in not enough. Are you in Winforms?

Comment: Well, I know about `DateTime.Now`, though Im not sure how to do Date comparrisons in C#.

Comment: See the answer, you probably have to compare the value to Today and not Now

Comment: Any feedback from you?

Comment: Both `DateTime.Today` and `DateTimePicker` return differently formated strings at first glance. Looking into how to reformat the picker text... I wanna say I can...

Answer (score 0):

Compare the DatePicker value to DateTime.Today.

You are probably comparing it to DatetTime.Now, but this gives you the exact time (date + hour, minutes and seconds). DateTime.Today is just Year, Month and Day.